# point subdomain to subfolder htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I want to create new subdomain for mobile site. so i want to point this domain to subfolder in root folder in my server:

Example:
www.mywebsite.com   point to www folder

I will create sub folder inside wwww name it: mobile_version
I will create subdomain for mobile name it: m.mywebsite.com
I want to point m.mywebsite.com to mobile_version folder **NOT REDIRECT**

if someone open mywebsite from mobile then will redirect to m.mywebsite.com and show the index.php inside mobile_version without redirect to m.mywebsite.com/mobile-version

I hope I passed my issue.

what I did in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.jeelplus.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.jeelplus.com/mobile_version/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this in `.htaccess`. Set the `DocumentRoot` appropriately in your `httpd.conf` file (or whatever you happen to have it called)

Answer (score 1):

if `m.jeelplus.com` is going to map to the sub-directory, then why are you passing the sub-directory as a URI parameter?  Also if you want it to re-map, NOT redirect then you can't have [R=301] because this is a redirect...

Your application also needs to determine whether the user is coming from mobile or not, and redirect to your `m.jeelplus.com` this can't really be done through .htaccess

your .htaccess will literally redirect every request into the server that isn't `m.jeelplus.com` to `m.jeelplus.com/mobile_version/`  this is probably not what you actually want to do..

I assume you want to rewrite anything coming into `m.jeelplus.com` to use `/mobile_version/index.php`

in which case try something more like:

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^m.jeelplus.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mobile_version/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Alternative setup a new vhost with its document root pointed to the mobile version folder with the ServerName m.jeelplus.com  and use the normal remap .htaccess...

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m.jeelplus.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !mobile_version/
RewriteRule (.*) /mobile_version/$1 [L]

Comment: don't forget to mark correct if this worked for you.